# time series array database for python

Tags: python, time-series

We have a fairly big db about our traffic.
We have over 1000 trains daily where we gather from different sources either on minute or event bases (a train is arrived a a station, a car or loc composition has changed etc.)
The db has over 100M rows actually in MSSQL.
It turns out that 90% of the data is redundant, just the time, the station, where the train passed and the distance is changing.
Insert/update and reasonably simple queries are fine. 
But when it comes to make statistical queries (like how many KM was a specific train/car/loc running in a given period of time) the response time and also the query complexity becomes important. (response needed within a 1-2 sec range).

What kind of DB/storage solution could I use for this kind of queries?
We have a python (Flask) front end for reporting so a DB solution having a python interface is a kind of must.

I've considered Pytables/pyhdf5 but I have some concerns about the reliability (I cannot guarantee that only on process will write the file so as per the documentation the risk of data corruption is high. And I cannot afford loose the data.

Side note: I'm quite OK with DB optimization so I know fairly well the relational limit.

And idea?

Comment: To plug an in-house solution built at one of my former employers -- you might see the [various talks on Imhotep](http://engineering.indeedblog.com/talks/). See also http://opensource.indeedeng.io/imhotep/. Not for everything, but it does provide quite good performance on the kinds of queries it does well, and scales to substantial amounts of data.

Comment: That said, the above is a comment rather than an answer because requests for software recommendations are explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow; see #4 in "some questions are still off-topic" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look on that.